# CodeIgniter 2 not setting csrf cookie on CentOS 6.5

Tags: cookies, codeigniter-2, csrf

Here's the form code:

```
<form action="http://142.54.168.154/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token_name" value="e255a710dae7c46526b285e95e18cf2b" />
</div>
<div>Email *</div>
<div><input type="text" name="email" value=""/></div>
<div>Password *</div>
<div><input type="password" name="pw"/></div>
<div>GAuth (optional, but required if enabled on your account)</div>
<div><input type="text" name="gauth"/></div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/></div>
</form>
```

I have verified in \system\core\Security.php fctn csrf_verify() that $_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] is set, but $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name] is empty.

This code runs properly on a different server so can someone suggest a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, in application\config\config.php set $config['cookie_domain'] to the ip address of the site. 
Developing on the ip address since DNS still hasn't resolved.